# Check for extends

Tags: php, class, oop, extends

I try to detect of one is extends by another, but it just doesn't work.. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
class Main
{
}

class Sub extends Main
{
}

class Third
{
}

$check = class_extends('Sub', 'Main'); // should return true
$check = class_extends('Third', 'Main'); // should return false
```

So is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: http://us2.php.net/is_subclass_of or http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.issubclassof.php

Comment: -1: You have not shown the definition of `class_extends` so far in your question, your example is just some way to create a fatal error: https://eval.in/private/b07f7f108a21ea - And yes, reading the manual helps: https://eval.in/private/82c1d451318bb2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible. I think you where looking for [`instanceof`](http://php.net/instanceof).

```
$object = new Sub;
var_dump($object instanceof Main);
```

This will output `bool(true)`.

Compare with the [*Example #3 Using instanceof to check if object is not an instanceof a class* on php.net](http://php.net/instanceof#example-129):

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
}

$a = new MyClass;
var_dump(!($a instanceof stdClass));
?>
```

Comment: This is actually not what asked for: Object creation. Question covers class-names not objects, see https://eval.in/private/b3b6ebcb076f1a - Also it does not check for a parent (subclass), but any type, so a Main would be an instance of a Main as well, which is most likely not what such a question would aim for. But I can understand that these problems arise from this type of questionable question.

Answer (score 11):

You might be looking for [`is_subclass_of`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-subclass-of.php). Works with instances and string class names too, lets say you have these classes:

```
class B {}
class C extends B {}
class A {}
```

Then

```
var_dump(is_subclass_of('C', 'B')); // true, C is subclass of B
var_dump(is_subclass_of('C', 'A')); // false C is not subclass of A
```

Or if you like skinny arrows (`->`) you can use [reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.issubclassof.php) too:

```
$refC = new ReflectionClass('C');
var_dump($refC->isSubclassOf('B')); // true, C is subclass of B
var_dump($refC->isSubclassOf('A')); // false C is not subclass of A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stick to a function you want by instantiating the first parameter:

```
function class_extends($class, $superclass) {
    if ((new $class) instanceof $superclass) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

class_extends('Sub', 'Main'); // boolean true
```

Comment: There is no need to create an instance here in PHP.

Comment: Honestly, I was never used the `is_subclass_of` function, so that made me answer with `instanceof` which needs instance of the class, I guess if I put it just as a string it will return false. Anyway, your solution is far more right :)

Comment: I have not placed any solution on my own :) , I just wanted to let you know as I quickly read over your answer while reviewing this Q&A entry.